# How to move data from one column to another in sqlite3

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I need some help formatting a table in sqlite3. I need to move all data points starting with the text "Source:" from the column they are in right now titled "Date" and put them in the column titled "Source".

I am using Python and also DB Browser. To be clear I am not trying to move all of the data points in column "Date" just the data points that start with "Source:"

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign values of attributes of a row to another attribute of the row within an `UPDATE`.

```
UPDATE elbat
       SET source = date
       WHERE date LIKE 'Source:%';
```

(Add `date = NULL` if you also want to delete the contents of `date` in the respective rows.)

Comment: Awesome! Thank you!